# Pulling Switch SNMP Communinties List with Python pysnmp

Tags: python, pysnmp

The code below works for other OIDs such as hostname (1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0) however I am having trouble with pulling the SNMP communities table (list of allowed ips for snmp).

I searched for "communities" for cisco in http://www.mibdepot.com/ and found 5 OIDs. All of which did not pull anything:
.1.3.6.1.4.1.224.2.3.6.3.1
.1.3.6.1.4.1.224.2.3.6.1.0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.224.2.3.6.3
.1.3.6.1.4.1.224.2.3.6.4.1
.1.3.6.1.4.1.224.2.3.6.4

Any guidance on this would be much appreciated. Thank you!

```
from pysnmp import hlapi

def get(target, oids, credentials, port=161, engine=hlapi.SnmpEngine(), context=hlapi.ContextData()):
    handler = hlapi.getCmd(
        engine,
        credentials,
        hlapi.UdpTransportTarget((target, port)),
        context,
        *construct_object_types(oids)
    )
    return fetch(handler, 1)[0]
    
def construct_object_types(list_of_oids):
    object_types = []
    for oid in list_of_oids:
        object_types.append(hlapi.ObjectType(hlapi.ObjectIdentity(oid)))
    return object_types
    
def fetch(handler, count):
    result = []
    for i in range(count):
        try:
            error_indication, error_status, error_index, var_binds = next(handler)
            if not error_indication and not error_status:
                items = {}
                for var_bind in var_binds:
                    items[str(var_bind[0])] = cast(var_bind[1])
                result.append(items)
            else:
                raise RuntimeError('Got SNMP error: {0}'.format(error_indication))
        except StopIteration:
            break
    return result
    
def cast(value):
    try:
        return int(value)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        try:
            return float(value)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            try:
                return str(value)
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass
    return value

def getSNMPCommunities(ip):
    try:
        communities = get(ip, ['1.3.6.1.4.1.224.2.3.6.1.0'], hlapi.CommunityData('public'))
        return communities.get('1.3.6.1.4.1.224.2.3.6.1.0')
    except:
        return None
        
snmpCommunities = getSNMPCommunities('10.0.0.1')
print(type(snmpCommunities))
print(snmpCommunities)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible since SNMP read-only shouldn't have access to this information.

The solution I came up with was to login via SSH and read in the stdout.